# Best Android 2.0 development book?

Tags: android, android-2.0-eclair

I'm looking for a single book source for Android 2.0 development.
While I may be ok with a general Android development book, a book which covers 2.0 features is ideal.

What is the best Android 2.0 book out there, or upcoming?

Comment: How about now...? It's almost July 2010 and as a beginner getting into Android Development I'm finding a lot of the books mentioned in other threads are a bit out fo date. Looking forward to seeing more answers on this question!

Comment: This one looks pretty good from skimming it at the book store. http://pragprog.com/titles/eband3/hello-android

Answer (score 21, accepted):

At the time of this writing, the Android 2.0 SDK has been available for about 2.5 weeks. Hence, it will be months before you will be able to compare a wide range of print books specifically for their Android 2.0 coverage. I will be impressed if there are more than three authors with Android 2.0-ready books by the end of February 2010.

I can tell you that:

- [One of my books](http://commonsware.com/Android/) will be updated to be compatible with Android 2.0 within the next few days. However, there is little new in Android 2.0 that affects that specific title, and that book is available primarily in [digital form](http://commonsware.com/warescription).
- My [other two](http://commonsware.com/AdvAndroid) [main books](http://commonsware.com/AndTutorials) will be updated with some Android 2.0 content shortly -- digital editions by the end of the year, printed editions in early 2010.
- I am under the distinct impression that [Reto Meier](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Android-Application-Development.productCd-0470344717.html) and [Ed Burnette](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/eband/hello-android) are planning on updating their books.
- I do not know anyone else's plans in this area.

Comment: Given how quickly 1.6 and 2.0 came out, is it safe to assume that 2.0 will be around long enough to warrant books coming out on it? Or is 2.1 already in the works and going to drop soon?

Comment: I can't speak for the timetable of Android 2.1. In terms of books, publishers will have to make a choice as to how aggressively they want to update their titles. What I expect you will find is that a number of the books on the market will not get updated. Going back to the original question, checking out what version of Android a book supports is a fine criterion...it's just a wee bit soon for Android 2.0+. The good news for developers is that some of the better-quality books (mine, Mr. Meier's, Mr. Burnette's) look like they will be kept up to date. As for the rest, only time will tell.