# Android, iPhone, Symbian and Windows Mobile development learning material

Tags: iphone, android, windows, mobile, symbian

I would like to ask all of you if you know any good **books**, **articles** etc ... on development for these mobile platforms. I'm looking for learning material where the whole technology, OSes and development is discussed in ***great detail*** so i could gain a deeper understanding of the system as a whole.
So any *quick start* tutorial and stuff like that does not count.

Major thanks for all your replies.

Comment: Community Wiki? And would that be a dup of:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books

?

Comment: This is a duplicate of the following questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754093/good-book-for-windows-mobile-development , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005367/any-complete-best-book-for-learning-a-z-of-symbian-and-its-api , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690201/best-android-2-0-development-book , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449101/iphone-development-books

Answer (score 2):

I found the Android Developers website very useful
http://developer.android.com/index.html

I am fairly new to Android myself, but I dissected and annotated their LunarLander example so I could build a framework for my game from it and so far so good!

If you have the time aswell check out Chris Pruetts talk from Google IO, I love this guy!
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-62tRHLcHk

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Symbian books and resources: http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Symbian_Resources_and_Books.

Answer (score 1):

Mark Murphy (a.k.a. [**commonsware**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) on **Stack Overflow**) has written several books on Android development.  The most appropriate for an experienced programmer new to the platform might be [*`The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development`*](http://commonsware.com/Android/) currently in its third edition.  He seems to update publications regularly and therefore offers an annual subscription to all Commonsware publications, available in PDF, EPUB, and Kindle forms.

Also check out a [**Knol**](http://knol.google.com/k/android-programming#) written by Mark wherein other resources are listed.